# Set video mode to 1920x1080 (HD) or higher in kernel ASM (NASM assembler)

Tags: video, assembly, kernel, nasm, vesa

I would like to set the video mode in a ASM kernel I'm working on to a video mode 1920x1080 or higher (or at least higher than the usual limit in VESA). Is there anyway to do that, and if so, provide sample code?

I'm using NASM to code the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this would require direct communication with the graphics card in question. This is just what Nvidia/ATI drivers do for you, but you're out of luck unless your kernel supports windows/linux drivers ;)